# Gatsby JS Meta description is missing for SEO?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, seo, gatsby

I created an SEO component, but for some reason when I run my site through lighthouse or an SEO checker it says I'm missing a meta description.

Here is my SEO component

```
      import React from "react"
      import PropTypes from "prop-types"
      import { Helmet } from "react-helmet"
      import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"

      function SEO({ description, title, keywords, siteUrl, lang, meta }) {
        const { site } = useStaticQuery(
          graphql`
            query {
              site {
                siteMetadata {
                  description
                  keywords
                  title
                  siteUrl
                }
              }
            }
          `
        )

        const metaDescription = description || site.siteMetadata.description
        const defaultTitle = site.siteMetadata.title
        const metaUrl = siteUrl || site.siteMetadata.siteUrl
        const metaKeywords = keywords || site.siteMetadata.keywords

        return (
          <Helmet
            htmlAttributes={{
              lang,
            }}
            title={title}
            titleTemplate={defaultTitle ? `%s | ${defaultTitle}` : null}
            meta={[
              {
                property: `og:title`,
                content: title,
              },
              {
                property: `og:siteurl`,
                content: metaUrl,
              },
              {
                name: `keywords`,
                content: metaKeywords,
              },
              {
                property: `og:description`,
                content: metaDescription,
              },
              {
                property: `og:type`,
                content: `website`,
              },
            ].concat(meta)}
          />
        )
      }

      SEO.defaultProps = {
        lang: `en`,
        meta: [],
        description: ``,
      }

      SEO.propTypes = {
        description: PropTypes.string,
        lang: PropTypes.string,
        meta: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object),
        title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      }

      export default SEO
```

When I inspect my site, it shows

```
 <meta data-react-helmet="true" property="og:description" content="My coding blog about tech 
 and design.">
```

So I'm not sure what I need to add or change for my SEO component because my current method of showing the description isn't working apparently based off lighthouse or the other SEO website checkers.

Comment: What if you try writing it using components inside of Helmet component like in the example from docs: https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet#example. Does that work?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `og:description` to `description` (standalone):

```
          {
            property: `description`,
            content: metaDescription,
          },
```

`og` attributes stands for **O**pen **G**raph. They are mostly used for social networks to get information when a web is shared, you can customize the description for those social networks instead of taking the description of the page itself. If you don't care about that, change it to `description`, if you do, keep both meta tags:

```
          {
            property: `og:description`,
            content: anoterOgMetaDescription,
          },
          {
            property: `description`,
            content: metaDescription,
          },
```